# How to fix the websocket connection fail in django channels 3 on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, websocket, redis

I am trying to deploy my Django channels app on Heroku.

**Problem:** Websocket fails to connect. Looking at the Heroku logs, this is what I find.

```
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080386+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'RedisChannelLayer' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

The app runs fine locally, and all the problems are caused when deploying. I have followed the docs and searched for the solutions, but I've been unable to find a solution for it.

I am using django 3.2.5, channels 3.0.4, channels-redis 3.3.0. Full requirements.txt file below.

**Full Log**

```
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080383+00:00 app[web.1]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 125, in dispatch
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080384+00:00 app[web.1]:     handler(message)
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 59, in websocket_receive
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080385+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080386+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./game/consumers.py", line 46, in receive
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080386+00:00 app[web.1]:     response["players_connected"] = len(self.channel_layer.groups.get(self.room_group_name, {}).items())
2021-08-04T09:24:47.080386+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'RedisChannelLayer' object has no attribute 'groups'
2021-08-04T09:24:47.332491+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.153.32:29310 - - [04/Aug/2021:09:24:47] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/game/4a676965" - -
2021-08-04T09:24:47.335311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ws/game/4a676965" host=blackjack-django.herokuapp.com request_id=8a46781c-ee66-4c63-bbef-cb1c6e2bf7a2 fwd="146.196.34.235" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1243ms status=101 bytes=145 protocol=https
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgi-redis==1.4.3
asgiref==3.4.1
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
autobahn==21.3.1
Automat==20.2.0
cffi==1.14.6
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.3.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==3.4.7
daphne==3.0.2
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
hiredis==2.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.2
incremental==21.3.0
msgpack==1.0.2
msgpack-python==0.5.6
psycopg2==2.9.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pytz==2021.1
redis==2.10.6
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
Twisted==21.7.0
txaio==21.2.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
whitenoise==5.3.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
import django
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.urls import path
from game.consumers import GameRoom

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'blackjack.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
django.setup()

ws_patterns = [
    path("ws/game/<room_code>", GameRoom.as_asgi())
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(ws_patterns))
})
```

**settings.py -> CHANNEL_LAYERS**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', ('redis', 6379))],
        },
    },
}
```

**Procfile**

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne blackjack.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2 channel_layer
```

In my **consumers.py**, I am using the groups this way to get all the connected users to the channel,

```
response["players_connected"] = len(self.channel_layer.groups.get(self.room_group_name, {}).items())
```

I have tried switching from ReconnectingWebSocket to WebSocket, but that doesn't fix anything.

Any help with troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you could advise on which files you should prefer to see, I will happily update my question with the contents of the requested files.